# i am getting the popup when using the window.open, i didnt want to get the popup, link has to be open directly

Tags: php, jquery

```
$.post('<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/user/clickcode',{'ccode':ssid},function(res){
          if(res) {         //res will have url like http://google,com

          window.open(res);
}
```

Comment: $.post('<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/user/clickcoupon',{'ccode':ssid},function(res){
              if(res) {
              //window.location.href = res;
              window.open(res);

Answer (score 1):

Replace `window.open(res);` with `location.href = res;`

`window.open()` will open a new window while `location.href` will update the current window.